# Is there a better way to write these functions

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to create a 5 reel slot machine. I was wondering if there is a faster way of using my function only once instead of multiple times to return selected values for each reel. Each reel has 3 symbols. the function shuffles the array, then must randomly pick an item and remove it from the array so the same symbols doesnt appear on the same reel twice. I am using the code below 5 times (For each reel) but was wondering if I could just use one function and reset it for every reel once 3 items have been selected and removed.

```
def my_function():

symbolsreel1 = ['Symbol1', 'Symbol2', 'Symbol3', 'Symbol4', 'Symbol5', ' 
Symbol6', 'Symbol7', 'Symbol8', 'Symbol9',
        'Symbol10', 'Symbol11', 'Symbol12',]


random.shuffle(symbolsreel1)
symbolItem = random.choice(symbolsreel1)
symbolsreel1.remove(symbolItem)


return(symbolItem)

a1 = my_function()
b1 = my_function()
c1 = my_function()

def my_function():

symbolsreel2 = ['Symbol1', 'Symbol2', 'Symbol3', 'Symbol4', 'Symbol5', 
'Symbol6', 'Symbol7', 'Symbol8', 'Symbol9',
        'Symbol10', 'Symbol11', 'Symbol12',]


random.shuffle(symbolsreel2)
symbolItem = random.choice(symbolsreel2)
symbolsreel2.remove(symbolItem)


return(symbolItem)

a2 = my_function()
b2 = my_function()
c2 = my_function()
```

I do this 5 times and print the following

```
print (a1, "\t", a2, "\t", a3, "\t", a4, "\t", a5)
print (b1, "\t", b2, "\t", b3, "\t", b4, "\t", b5)
print (c1, "\t", c2, "\t", c3, "\t", c4, "\t", c5)
```

Comment: you would need to have the symbols list as global if you need multiple calls to remove selected items from symbol list. Also `random.shuffle` is redundant (not needed) since you use `random.choice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already shuffling the symbol list, you don't need to randomly choose from it because the elements will already be randomly arranged.

Just use random.shuffle() like you have and then return the first 3 elements at once:

```
def my_function():
    symbolsreel = ['Symbol1', 'Symbol2', 'Symbol3', 'Symbol4', 'Symbol5', 'Symbol6', 'Symbol7', 'Symbol8', 'Symbol9', 'Symbol10', 'Symbol11', 'Symbol12',]
    random.shuffle(symbolsreel)
    return symbolsreel[:3]

[a1, b1, c1] = my_function()
```

If the symbols to choose from are the same on all 5 reels, then you can also do all 5 reels in one function call:

```
def my_function():
    symbolsreel = ['Symbol1', 'Symbol2', 'Symbol3', 'Symbol4', 'Symbol5', 'Symbol6', 'Symbol7', 'Symbol8', 'Symbol9', 'Symbol10', 'Symbol11', 'Symbol12',]
    reels = []
    for i in range(5):
        random.shuffle(symbolsreel)
        reels[i] = symbolsreel[:3]
    return reels

[[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3], etc...] = my_function() # replace "etc..." with actual code
```

Comment: in the first example I am able to print the outcome with print (my_function()). How do I print the outcome in the second example once I have set [[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3], [a4, b4, c4], [a5, b5, c5]] = my_function() Thank you.

Comment: figured it out. was missing reels.append(1) before random.shuffle.